# Hide / Show Tab text on click

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, onclick

I have a set of tabs. I want to always show glyphs for each tab but show/hide their text depending on if the specific tab is selected or not. I have managed to get the functionality I want with a jquery script but it feels like a very convoluted way of doing it and very, very wrong!

In my script, every time a tab is clicked, I "unhide" the text of the selected tab and hide the text of all other tabs. It doesn't look that bad on the example below (with two tabs) but it's horrendous when even more tabs are included.

Can you please advise if there's a simpler way of doing it? I include a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j1pn7706/) with the examples. 
My code below:

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-12 column">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li><a id="btn-tab1" data-toggle="tab" href="#section-one"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-paperclip"></i><i id="tab1-text" style="display: none"> Tab 1 Name</i></a>

    </li>
    <li><a id="btn-tab2" data-toggle="tab" href="#section-two"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-education"></i><i id="tab2-text" style="display: none"> Tab 2 Name</i></a>

    </li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
            if ($("#btn-tab1").attr('aria-expanded') == 'true') {
                $("#tab1-text").show();
                $("#tab2-text").hide();
            } else if ($("#btn-tab2").attr('aria-expanded') == 'true') {
                $("#tab2-text").show();
                $("#tab1-text").hide();
            }
        })
    });
```

Comment: This question feels like it belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network [http://codereview.stackexchange.com/](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I will move it there. Thanks.

Comment: Use this OP http://jsfiddle.net/j1pn7706/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To improve the use of your function it's better if you refer to the element itself instead of always use the `id` attribute. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').find('.glyphicon').next().hide();
    $(this).find('i').show();
  })
});
```

#### [FiddleDemo](http://jsfiddle.net/j1pn7706/1/)

Comment: Glad to help U @ChristakisSchinis